# How to bulk mint token in a particular wallet in sugar candy machine v2

Tags: solana-cli, transfer, mint, candy-machine-v2, sugar

If minting in the owner's account and then transferring it to the desired address then what is the most efficient way of doing that, so that I don't end up spending a fortune just on minting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command is
`sugar mint -n <no of tokens> --receiver <receiverWalletAddress>`
you can learn more about mint commands using `sugar mint --help`